# Change the icon of a single, specific file

Tags: macos, icon

I want to change the icon of a single, specific file, eg. *not* all the docs file, only one .doc file (and this change should even persist). Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the image that you would like to be the icon in Preview.
2. Press ⌘A to select the entire image and press ⌘C to copy it.
3. Get Info (⌘I) on the folder.
4. Click the existing icon in the top-left and press ⌘V to paste the icon from Preview.

To revert back to the default icon, Get Info on the folder, click your icon and press ⌫.

Comment: Ok, but what if I totally remove the original image from my disk? That is: I suspect this "only" creates a link to my image. Please, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Ian This pastes the image data into the image well, so the image data is copied and does not reference the original.